# BubbleSort algorithm in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, bubble-sort

So I was trying to practice JS and decided to go for bubble sort algorithm.
I wrote the code below and realized that it doesn't work when there's a 3 digit number in the array.
I run the code in Chrome's console.
Can anyone tell me what the problem is?

```
var array = [];

var length = prompt("Please enter length of array: ");

for (count = 0; count < length; count++) {
  array.push(prompt("Enter a number: "));
}

for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
  for (j = 0; j < length - i - 1; j++) {
    if (array[j] > array[j + 1]) {
      var temp = array[j];
      array[j] = array[j + 1];
      array[j + 1] = temp;
    }
  }
}

console.log("Your list of numbers is sorted!" + array);
```

Comment: You have to convert the inputed digits to numbers. For example `array.push(+prompt("Enter a number: "))` or `array.push(Number(prompt("Enter a number: ")))`

Comment: `prompt` returns a string and strings are compared alphabetically. You need to convert each user input into a number. `array.push(Number(prompt("Enter a number: ")));`

Comment: Note that the complexity can be simplified. If during a whole inner loop you don't perform any swap, then the array is sorted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`Window.prompt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt) function returns a `string`, so you should convert it to `number` with [`Number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) (else `<` would compare them alphabetically), *e.g.*

```js
var arr = [];
var len = parseInt(prompt("Please enter length of array: "));
for (count = 0; count < len; count++) {
  arr.push(Number(prompt("Enter a number: ")));
}
for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < len - i - 1; j++) {
    if (arr[j] > arr[j + 1]) {
      let tmp = arr[j];
      arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
      arr[j + 1] = tmp;
    }
  }
}
console.log("Your list of numbers is sorted: " + arr);
```

Comment: Two notes: `Number()` would also allow floats; Should make a habbit to add the `Radix` to `parseInt()`.